# Calling a Stored Procedure from NHibernate and retrieving @@ROWCOUNT

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, nhibernate

After trying to work this out for a few hours, I'm beginning to think I can't solve this without your help. Situation:

My stored procudure in SQL Server Management Studio (basically):

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DELETE myTable
...                    -- Complex join query that deletes duplicates
RETURN @@ROWCOUNT      -- The number of rows affected
```

This procedure works well, if I run it in SSMS the following query is run:

```
USE myDb
GO
DECLARE @return_value int
EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[StoredProcedure]
        @var1 = N'asd',
        @var2 = N'fgh',
        @var3 = N'jkl'
SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
GO
```

The result is shown as 1 row with name `Return Value` and value `8700` (this is **correct**, it's the number of rows that was deleted by the query).

My problems begin in my C#/NHibernate code. In my NHibernate mapping:

```
<sql-query name="MyStoredProcedureName">
  exec dbo.StoredProcedure @var1=:var1, @var2=:var2, @var3=:var3
</sql-query>
```

In my method where I call the stored procedure:

```
var deletedEntities = session.GetNamedQuery("MyStoredProcedureName")
                             .SetString("var1", "asd")
                             .SetString("var2", "fgh")
                             .SetString("var3", "jkl")
                             .ExecuteUpdate();
```

This results in `deletedEntities = -1`. I would like it to be `deletedEntities = 8700`.

I'd like to point out that the following **did** return the number of affected rows:

```
var deletedEntities = session.CreateQuery("DELETE Class c WHERE c.var1 = :var1 AND c.var2 = :var2 AND c.var3 = :var3")
                             .SetString("var1", var1)
                             .SetString("var2", var2)
                             .SetString("var3", var3)
                             .ExecuteUpdate();
```

Where `Class` is the class that belongs to the NHibernate mapping.

So, to summarize:

1. ExecuteUpdate on a SIMPLE `session.CreateQuery` gives me back the number of affected rows (GOOD)
2. ExecuteUpdate on a COMPLEX `session.GetNamedQuery` gives me back `-1` (BAD)
3. This same complex stored procedure gives me back the desired `8700` when I execute it in SSMS (GOOD)

Anyone has an idea of how to fix 2?

Comment: Your question is very similar to these questions but they return `-1` for all cases in **entity framework**  have a look at them here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32140774/getting-data-from-stored-procedure-with-entity-framework/ And here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31709284/stored-procedure-return-1-for-all-cases-in-entity-framwork

Comment: Thank you, reading in to it now.

Comment: @S.Akbari I'm kind of confused by the first variable they create (db), and how they call the stored procedure. It's completely different from how I call it within NHibernate. Also I don't see how to "Import the stored procedure as a Function. Right-click on the workspace area of your Entity model and choose Add -> Function Import." (This must be one of the most idiotic questions, but what is the workspace area of my Entity model? :S).

Comment: What about changing your stored procedure as suggested in the second link?

Comment: Using words from the two links you gave, I googled some more and found this: http://csharptechies.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/how-to-get-return-value-from-stored.html which actually seems to work. I am going to look into this solution combined with the `GetNamedQuery` (mapped) `.ExecuteUpdate()` combination instead of the `CreateSQLQuery` and `.UniqueResult` combination.

Answer (score 2):

Using http://csharptechies.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/how-to-get-return-value-from-stored.html I got my code working. In the procedure, replaced `RETURN @@ROWCOUNT` with `SELECT @@ROWCOUNT`

In the C# code, I replaced `.ExecuteUpdate()` with `.UniqueResult()`. UniqueResult returns an object, which will contain the `@@ROWCOUNT` value (need to convert to int as stated in the link above).

So the solution is a combination (I'd like to use the mapping):

1. Use `SELECT` instead of `RETURN`
2. Use .`UniqueResult()` instead of `.ExecuteUpdate()`

Edit: I got another problem, the query had a timeout whenever there was a large number of records to be removed. I fixed this with the help of other questions, such as [SQL Server: Effects of using 'WITH RECOMPILE' in proc definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831085/sql-server-effects-of-using-with-recompile-in-proc-definition).

3. Use `WITH RECOMPILE` in a complex query on large tables (my query involved a `left outer join`, `min(id)` and `group by`'s, the number of records to be affected are often around 20.000 but can run up to 100.000+ and my table has over 350.000.000 records in it) to avoid timeouts.

Comment: I have done so :) I get an error at this moment which I didn't get yesterday, so it might not be working still :( I'll get back to it asap.

Comment: I feel like the query worked because I used data that did not exist. If I use Var1, Var2 and Var3 and set them to `value_does_not_exist` the query is executed. As soon as it finds data, it gives me an error saying `could not execute query ... [SQL: exec StoredProcedureName @p0, @p1, @p2]` **edit**: it does not give this error when I use values that are NOT in the database. Very strange? Does it have something to do with the return value/delete rights or something? :S

Comment: Not sure what exactly happened but as you guessed I think it might be the the return value issue. I don't know about *NHibernate* but EF cannot support stored procedure return scalar values out of the box.

Comment: @S.Akbari I found out what the problem is, not sure how to solve yet: it worked when there are 3 duplicated values (it removes 2 of them in no time at all). However, when there are 78297 records to be removed, the query times out. The conclusion: my query is bad and I should feel bad. **BUT** when I run the stored procedure from SSMS, it takes 4 seconds to delete the 78297 records. So the question is, why does the query take more than 30 seconds (and time-outs) when I run it from Visual Studio (my web service).

Comment: I suggest you do this in EF also and compare the results.

Comment: Let me know what the problem was when you resolve it, I'm curious.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108409/discussion-between-tjab-and-s-akbari).